# Failed update on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt

I have a problem in the run of `sudo apt-get update` on Ubuntu 12.04.
I get below errors :

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.   
Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file).
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I solve the issue?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please post the contents of the file ´/etc/apt/sources.list´

Answer (score 0):

12.04 runs out of support in nine days time; after five years of support and service; so many would recommend you make plans immediately to install a new version that can give you continued support

http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/